# iOS application crashes when button is clicked iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using xcode 4.2 and ARC. Below is the code I am using. When I click on any button my application crashes and it highlights this code in main.m

Sometimes I get this error

```
-[__NSCFTimer parentLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and sometimes application crashes without any error.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

My code is:

In my ViewController.m I am using this code to get to the ChooseLogin view controller.

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {


    ChooseLogin *loginScreen = [[ChooseLogin alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseLogin" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:loginScreen.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then in ChooseLogin.m:

```
@implementation ChooseLogin


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)parentLogin:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@":::::::");

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *passwd = [prefs stringForKey:@"password"];

    NSLog(@"data saved");

    if (passwd == nil) {


    CreatePassword *cPassword = [[CreatePassword alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreatePassword" bundle:nil ];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:cPassword.view];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }else {

        UserPassword *uPasswd = [[UserPassword alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserPassword" bundle:nil];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:uPasswd.view];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}

- (IBAction)childLogin:(id)sender {

    ChildLogin *loginScreen = [[ChildLogin alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildLogin" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
   // [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:loginScreen.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to examine how the `UIView` subclasses are defined in Interface Builder nib file, as you likely have hooked up the custom view to a selector (method) that does not exist. You have to write the selector being called when you tap the view.

Comment: Couldn't get it... Do you mean the controllers I am calling might have the issue ?

Comment: I have edited my question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-[__NSCFTimer parentLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This means that a message is being sent to a class that the class doesn't recognize -- you either haven't written this custom selector (function), or somehow a function is being sent to the wrong class and therefore isn't recognized.  XCode is usually pretty good about catching these when trying to write code, but it doesn't seem to check for them in XIB files.

The most frequent cause of this type of issue, in my experience, is when you delete or rename a function, and forget to update the XIB file associated with that class -- or you do update it, and it adds the new version of the function, without forgetting the old one.

Comment: Basically this. After making changes to a nib file or, instead, to a class definition, it's easy to forget to make changes to the other file...

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not add view of one view controller to another.
2. If you still want to do this. You create controller, take it's view amnd then it get released, because you store reference to it nowhere. make ivar `loginScreen` and ARC will retain `ChooseLogin` controller for you.

Comment: [Use modal controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html). Also  you will probably need to make a protocol to return chosen value if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- why not add the view of one view controller to another view as a sub view?  Or are you saying that I shouldn't set ViewController1.view=viewController2.view?

Comment: It was somewhere in apple docs.I worked with applications made in such way and it is very bad approach. If you want only a view, make a subclass of it. If you want a controller for view, make subclass of `NSObject` that will have and manage it's own `UIView` add it to your viewControoler's view, but don't forget to retain your custom controller.